# Not allowing touch interaction on certain views?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a class where I handle my touches functions on buttons, and those buttons are also a Post class.

The logic I'm going for is "If the post.user is equal to the current firebaseuser, don't allow the user to move the button"

Here's what I tried:

In my "DragButtonsClass" I've got a notification being sent to my view controller on TouchesBegan.

In the view I've got

```
func touchesStarted(notif : NSNotification)  {
    if let dict = notif.userInfo! as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {

          let tag = dict["tag"]!
          let tagInt = Int(String((tag))) //this is probably super sloppy, don't know how else to change an AnyObject to an Int though.
          let post = postArray[tagInt! - 1]

        let postbutton = self.view.viewWithTag(tagInt!)
        if post.user  == currentUser {


        postbutton?.userInteractionEnabled = false
        print("Should be working")
        } else {
            print("Didn't work")
        }

    }

}
```

Basically I'm assigning tags to the buttons as they're created and those tags line up with my Posts array. I'm trying to check if the Post's user is the same as the current user by sending it over and then shut off user interaction.

I'm getting "Should be working" to print out but the button is still draggable.

This seems like a super sloppy and roundabout way to do this and most importantly it isn't working.  I've read that turning off userInteraction is a way to stop touches from being recognized.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would change your code a little bit. I guess that you want to reach some buttons, where (if a user is allowed to) can add some comments. Why not create your buttons, with an normal click event, and check in the click event handler, if the user is allowed or not? And, if the user is not allowed, you could grey out the button.

Comment: @derdida I'm needing to only allow users to move buttons they didn't create, so I'm trying to check the creator by checking the tag and then my Post class array with that index, and checking the post.user on it.

I've got that bit working, like I can detect if the user on that button is the current user is the right one, I just don't know how to prevent the touches moved then from happening.

I also lost my built in I guess? on touch button clicking when I made the button my own custom class or when I added the touches began?

I thought not allowing user interaction would work but nah

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just setting a bool "canBeDragged" in my button's class, and when the button is created the current user's ID is compared to the information being pulled from firebase and the bool is set. Then I just checked if the button could be dragged before my touchesMoved.